# Best practice for extending props of wrapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please have a look at the following snippet:

```
class Placeholder extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>;
  }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const childs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, idx) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        title: this.props.conf[child.props.name]
      });
    });
    return <div>{childs}</div>
  }
}

function App() {
  const conf = {
    "1": "test1",
    "2": "test2",
  };
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper conf={conf}>
        <Placeholder name="1" />
        <Placeholder name="2" />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(link: https://codesandbox.io/s/93wwyz05ry)

In this I have a Wrapper and a Placeholder component. You can place Placeholders inside the Wrapper component; the Wrapper will receive a config prop, that includes information for the wrapped Placeholder components. The Placeholder components reference the relevant config value by providing a name.
(please keep in mind: the example doesn‘t make much sense, but should only demonstrate the basic idea; you can think of it as a template engine)

In the case that Placeholders are direct children of Wrapper this works totally great, but what I want to achieve is, that I can also deeply nest Placeholder components inside of Wrapper. So something like this, should also be possible:

```
<Wrapper conf={conf}>
    <div>
         <Placeholder name="1" />
    </div>
    <Placeholder name="2" />
</Wrapper>
```

To achieve this I can think of two options at the moment:

1. Create a recursive function in the Wrapper component, that just loops through all the children, grandchildren, etc.
2. Change up the process: Add a function to Wrapper, that gets as a parameter Placeholder component and the specific configuration and returns an already extended Placeholder component. (~ HOC approach)

Number 1 can be pretty bad for the performance I guess.

Number 2 would work, but I don‘t really like it, as I would prefer to keep everything "together", like the basic idea/structure is at the moment.

Am I right with the performance issues, or wouldn‘t it be too bad? Do you have another idea?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not only on an external site. Also, asking for opinions is generally off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you have some objective measure of what answers should provide, that would be good to include.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the info. I edited my answer!